# Parsing "Fri, 02 Dec 2016 12:29:00 +0100" to OffsetDateTime in Java

Tags: java, date, parsing

I'm kind of stuck when trying to parse the following string in Java

```
Fri, 02 Dec 2016 12:29:00 +0100
```

My approach using the OffsetDateTime was the following:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss xx");
OffsetDateTime time = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);
```

where "dateString" is the string obove. 
Am I missing something?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Works for me, are you in the right `Locale`?

Comment: What's the problem? If you mean the parser complains about the input string it might be the problem that Sotirios pointed at: if you're using a `Locale` that doesn't understand "Fri" and "Dec" you'll get parsing errors, thus try `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss xx", Locale.ENGLISH)`

Comment: Beside the above, text based io operations (e.g. reading/writing/parsing/formatting strings etc.) should _always_ make use of an explicit `Locale` and encoding, otherwise the system default would be used which could be different on another machine (or even on yours over time). - As an example: we once had a system which had German as its system locale and some csv import relied on that. An OS update changed that locale to English and thus our import misinterpreted the numbers in the csv file, i.e. 1.0 became 10 etc.

Comment: Thanks so much. You were right. I was in the wrong `Locale` 
I used the predefined formatter. That worked too and I'm not dependent on the `Locale`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use predefined formatter

The `DateTimeFormatter` class provides a constant instance for that input string. That string format is defined by [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123). Use the constant [`DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME).

```
String input = "Fri, 02 Dec 2016 12:29:00 +0100";
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse ( input , DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME );
```

> odt.toString(): 2016-12-02T12:29+01:00

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/CpWQk8).

English seems to be built into this formatter. Your JVM’s current default `Locale` is irrelevant. Adding a line such as `Locale.setDefault ( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH );` to the above code has no impact. So, while the comments above give good advice to always specify a `Locale` rather than rely implicitly on the current default, this particular formatter is an exception.